# Accumulate total sum based on value of cells across multiple worksheets

Tags: excel-formula, sumifs

I am looking for a formula in excel that will calculate the sum of a given cell based on the value in a different cell, across all worksheets.

That is, I would only like the sum of a cell based on the criteria of another column, across multiple worksheets if the value matches.

```
Worksheet 1
19  apples
2   oranges
57  pears

Worksheet 2
2   apples
13  oranges
3   pears
```

Summary
apples: (from all worksheets)

I would like to know how many apples I have total from every worksheet, but have not been able to properly work out the sum-if...if thats the correct tool. The sums I want to add are always in the same column across worksheets, and the criteria is always in the same column. But criteria column is never in the same order

Comment: it is called [3D SUMIFS](https://exceljet.net/formula/3d-sumif-for-multiple-worksheets)

Comment: Thanks. I think I found something.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I used was this:

Input this formula into the desired Total Cell on your summary or totals worksheet

```
=SUM(Worksheet1:Worksheet2!<cell>)
```

So if in worksheet1 you have

```
A1  B1
19  apples
2   oranges
57  pears
```

And in worksheet2 you have

```
A1  B1
2   apples
13  oranges
3   pears
```

The formula that would go on your summary or totals worksheet for total apples would be as follows:

```
=SUM(Worksheet1:Worksheet2!A1)
```